# Trying to create a Mysql query to find the max in my table but I need advice

Tags: java, mysql

Hi  I am trying to create a query that will look at the table and find the salesmen that has the highest Total Sold but I keep getting an error when I try to do it like this. I want the entire row so that I can display it on a table that I binded to the table.

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:`

```
SELECT s From Salesmen s Where s.totalSold = MAX(totalSold)
```

Comment: Use `*` rather than `s` in your select list.

Comment: added the `Java` tag. Tweak accordingly, good luck !

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT * 
From Salesmen s 
Where s.totalSold = (SELECT MAX(totalSold) FROM Salesmen)
```